# Identity Server 4. Token Endpoint, Password Grant. How do I check acr_values?

Tags: identityserver4

I suspect this is very simple but I can't find exactly what I need to do.

I am trying to get a password Grant enabled, token endpoint, working with name/password/SomethingExtra

It all works with just name and password. I can see my "Data:SomethingExtra" in acr_values on the server but only in the GetProfileDataAsync override.

So, I can pick up the acr_values in the token generation (GetProfileDataAsync) but I want to "validate" the user with this extra data. How do I test my acr_values at validation?

I suspect there is a method I can override to pick up the "login request" with the extra acr_values so I can decide to return a token or Access Denied much the same was I do with an interactive login using Quickstart web pages.

But what do I override to allow me to authenticate against 3 values?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using password grant then you will have implemented `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` to validate your passwords.   You can get the acr values in this class as follows:

```
public async Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context) {
    string acrValues = context.Request.Raw.Get("acr_values");
    IEnumerable<string> values = acrValues.Trim().Split(new[] { ' ' });
    string extraDataAcr = values.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith("ExtraData:"));
    string extraDataValue extraDataAcr?.Substring("ExtraData:".Length);
```

Comment: I found a solution using TokenRequestValidator. When I was experimenting the PasswordValidator wasn't hit.  No idea why :)  I suspect it only get hit on a validation endpoint, not the token endpoint

Comment: Perhaps you are using `AddTestUsers` which adds `TestUserResourceOwnerPasswordValidator`?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of digging...might save someone some time

```
public class ACustomTokenRequestValidator : ICustomTokenRequestValidator
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public ACustomTokenRequestValidator(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task ValidateAsync(CustomTokenRequestValidationContext context)
    {
        if (context?.Result?.ValidatedRequest?.GrantType != null &&
            context.Result.ValidatedRequest.GrantType.ToUpper() == "PASSWORD")  // Only interested in password Grant
        {
            var acr_values = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            string username = string.Empty;
            string error = string.Empty;
            string Tester = string.Empty;

            bool ok = true;

            if (context.Result.ValidatedRequest.Raw != null)
            {
                var reqParamsDict = context.Result.ValidatedRequest.Raw.ToDictionary();

                if (reqParamsDict.ContainsKey("acr_values"))
                {
                    var raw = reqParamsDict["acr_values"].Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
                    acr_values = raw.Select(item => item.Split(':', 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).ToDictionary(s => s[0], s => s[1]);
                }

                if (reqParamsDict.ContainsKey("username"))   // Should always be there, name/password check would have failed already
                {
                    username = reqParamsDict["username"];
                }
                else
                {
                    ok = false;
                    error = "username missing from request";
                }

                if (ok && acr_values.ContainsKey("ExtraField"))   // Could be missing
                {
                    Tester = acr_values["ExtraField"];
                }
                else
                {
                    ok = false;
                    error = "ExtraField missing from request";
                }

                if (ok)
                {
                    if (context.Result.ValidatedRequest.Scopes.Contains("API_Name"))
                    {
                        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);

                        if (user != null)
                        {
                            if ( user.ExtraField != Tester )
                            { 
                                ok = false;
                                error = "Failed extra test";
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ok = false;
                            error = "User not found";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!ok)
            {
                context.Result.IsError = true;
                context.Result.Error = error;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
For completeness this is my Postman setup to get it working

  [https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtihJ.png][1]
```